# How can I remove someone's computer from my wireless network?

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm trying to remove someone's computer from my wifi, and I'm not sure how. I did the initial setup on my old laptop, and I no longer have it now. Please help.

Comment: Change the encryption password.  (Generally your router will be at 192.168.1.1.  Hopefully you remember the router password (which is different from the encryption password).)

Comment: Is [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/391064) also your question on AskUbuntu? Anyway, [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/391065) is your solution.

Comment: No this is my only question. How would I change the encryption password?

Comment: What is your WiFi access device model?

Answer (score 2):

Some routers have an option to block a certain computer's MAC address. It really depends on what type of router you have.

Answer (score 1):

Do as Tembrau says. See if you can block by the MAC address.

Otherwise, a simple way to do it is to change the wifi password and restart the router.

These settings can normally be accessed by going to the router's administration page at `192.168.1.1` or `192.168.0.1` in a web browser.